# Iterate parameter to function applied to a list of data sets using purrr

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

How can I pass a vector of values to to a function iteratively applied to a list of data sets? In my case I have a list of spatial points data sets I want to calculate a minimum convex polygon home range for over a range of percentages.  Some data for an example:

```
PERCENTS <- seq(25,95, by=10)

TEST_POINTS <-list(new("SpatialPointsDataFrame", data = structure(list(idcollar = c(84244L, 
84244L, 84244L, 84244L, 84244L, 84244L, 84244L, 84244L, 84244L, 
84244L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 10L)), coords.nrs = numeric(0), 
    coords = structure(c(-118.796672599079, -118.79583601152, 
    -118.795492312404, -118.796663656849, -118.796348126885, 
    -118.76308065785, -118.762391383061, -118.764679359412, -118.773199537493, 
    -118.806744760698, 51.9397090002744, 51.9389856110534, 51.9385156406006, 
    51.9397487508879, 51.9423713577809, 51.9161114304277, 51.9131726996881, 
    51.911575549113, 51.9103936467115, 51.9217444619829), .Dim = c(10L, 
    2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("coords.x1", "coords.x2"))), 
    bbox = structure(c(-118.806744760698, 51.9103936467115, -118.762391383061, 
    51.9423713577809), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(c("coords.x1", 
    "coords.x2"), c("min", "max"))), proj4string = new("CRS", 
        projargs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")), new("SpatialPointsDataFrame", 
    data = structure(list(idcollar = c(84245L, 84245L, 84245L, 
    84245L, 84245L, 84245L, 84245L, 84245L, 84245L, 84245L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    10L)), coords.nrs = numeric(0), coords = structure(c(-119.452800755831, 
    -119.451692603184, -119.446306291499, -119.443500481265, 
    -119.458752359107, -119.470254501473, -119.456958780954, 
    -119.457811626319, -119.459427588032, -119.458350112142, 
    52.1950552689039, 52.1916533654978, 52.189042742542, 52.1842978045074, 
    52.1750892928337, 52.1756021559288, 52.1798410478794, 52.1805752655884, 
    52.1819161798982, 52.1814375190128), .Dim = c(10L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
        NULL, c("coords.x1", "coords.x2"))), bbox = structure(c(-119.470254501473, 
    52.1750892928337, -119.443500481265, 52.1950552689039), .Dim = c(2L, 
    2L), .Dimnames = list(c("coords.x1", "coords.x2"), c("min", 
    "max"))), proj4string = new("CRS", projargs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")), 
    new("SpatialPointsDataFrame", data = structure(list(idcollar = c(84246L, 
    84246L, 84246L, 84246L, 84246L, 84246L, 84246L, 84246L, 84246L, 
    84246L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 10L)), 
        coords.nrs = numeric(0), coords = structure(c(-119.588527575438, 
        -119.585645041415, -119.563475346451, -119.5512424382, 
        -119.517577606708, -119.511556659379, -119.512023392923, 
        -119.511194601365, -119.509639295538, -119.510302348001, 
        52.1710067022501, 52.1728735312347, 52.195018104407, 
        52.193382156278, 52.2008927672771, 52.1997551430143, 
        52.1992985155389, 52.1996641627126, 52.199547467433, 
        52.2019063968289), .Dim = c(10L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
            NULL, c("coords.x1", "coords.x2"))), bbox = structure(c(-119.588527575438, 
        52.1710067022501, -119.509639295538, 52.2019063968289
        ), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(c("coords.x1", 
        "coords.x2"), c("min", "max"))), proj4string = new("CRS", 
            projargs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")), 
    new("SpatialPointsDataFrame", data = structure(list(idcollar = c(84251L, 
    84251L, 84251L, 84251L, 84251L, 84251L, 84251L, 84251L, 84251L, 
    84251L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 10L)), 
        coords.nrs = numeric(0), coords = structure(c(-119.476859063894, 
        -119.476339705663, -119.476699557504, -119.473824991484, 
        -119.435521712885, -119.424654955989, -119.415662245835, 
        -119.417115645576, -119.415351955525, -119.414245764292, 
        52.2187837322686, 52.2188063350676, 52.2165898415885, 
        52.2158121729737, 52.204019537989, 52.2031593354694, 
        52.1995108084414, 52.2007953520418, 52.199919544881, 
        52.1993937166707), .Dim = c(10L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
            NULL, c("coords.x1", "coords.x2"))), bbox = structure(c(-119.476859063894, 
        52.1993937166707, -119.414245764292, 52.2188063350676
        ), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(c("coords.x1", 
        "coords.x2"), c("min", "max"))), proj4string = new("CRS", 
            projargs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")), 
    new("SpatialPointsDataFrame", data = structure(list(idcollar = c(84252L, 
    84252L, 84252L, 84252L, 84252L, 84252L, 84252L, 84252L, 84252L, 
    84252L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 10L)), 
        coords.nrs = numeric(0), coords = structure(c(-119.629029468257, 
        -119.628985149542, -119.618103600142, -119.620660572006, 
        -119.628874605615, -119.630588457604, -119.634167258223, 
        -119.634657458965, -119.644139811651, -119.641638273026, 
        52.1925223521455, 52.1927583076881, 52.1870973461104, 
        52.1877171064421, 52.1882984217347, 52.1893357220181, 
        52.1924605149187, 52.193741167943, 52.198856043097, 52.203507029979
        ), .Dim = c(10L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("coords.x1", 
        "coords.x2"))), bbox = structure(c(-119.644139811651, 
        52.1870973461104, -119.618103600142, 52.203507029979), .Dim = c(2L, 
        2L), .Dimnames = list(c("coords.x1", "coords.x2"), c("min", 
        "max"))), proj4string = new("CRS", projargs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")), 
    new("SpatialPointsDataFrame", data = structure(list(idcollar = c(84253L, 
    84253L, 84253L, 84253L, 84253L, 84253L, 84253L, 84253L, 84253L, 
    84253L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 10L)), 
        coords.nrs = numeric(0), coords = structure(c(-119.015959328265, 
        -119.015091923273, -119.001746734699, -118.984291484541, 
        -118.976109681826, -118.993742711869, -119.002579806184, 
        -119.013774284853, -119.016673429073, -119.036674866425, 
        51.9891270943747, 51.9889561310395, 51.983682845278, 
        51.990694932117, 52.0039664134331, 51.9841576264947, 
        51.9841108054315, 51.9881110868242, 51.9862654011327, 
        51.9861690301565), .Dim = c(10L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
            NULL, c("coords.x1", "coords.x2"))), bbox = structure(c(-119.036674866425, 
        51.983682845278, -118.976109681826, 52.0039664134331), .Dim = c(2L, 
        2L), .Dimnames = list(c("coords.x1", "coords.x2"), c("min", 
        "max"))), proj4string = new("CRS", projargs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")), 
    new("SpatialPointsDataFrame", data = structure(list(idcollar = c(84263L, 
    84263L, 84263L, 84263L, 84263L, 84263L, 84263L, 84263L, 84263L, 
    84263L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 10L)), 
        coords.nrs = numeric(0), coords = structure(c(-118.986162057801, 
        -118.988961424403, -118.986439540502, -118.987382675356, 
        -118.992339349549, -118.992214572414, -118.989026749093, 
        -118.988725566142, -118.986860720538, -118.986512152757, 
        51.9563399635145, 51.9567793353248, 51.9559542931477, 
        51.9546065078554, 51.954853098071, 51.9552419279153, 
        51.9560342474978, 51.9552552266411, 51.9556797387135, 
        51.9548761346614), .Dim = c(10L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
            NULL, c("coords.x1", "coords.x2"))), bbox = structure(c(-118.992339349549, 
        51.9546065078554, -118.986162057801, 51.9567793353248
        ), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(c("coords.x1", 
        "coords.x2"), c("min", "max"))), proj4string = new("CRS", 
            projargs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")), 
    new("SpatialPointsDataFrame", data = structure(list(idcollar = c(84296L, 
    84296L, 84296L, 84296L, 84296L, 84296L, 84296L, 84296L, 84296L, 
    84296L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 10L)), 
        coords.nrs = numeric(0), coords = structure(c(-119.588190960814, 
        -119.582427587606, -119.563997706141, -119.551546896745, 
        -119.517204466735, -119.51134729973, -119.512128552246, 
        -119.510946824385, -119.509868345652, -119.510795043984, 
        52.1708538774377, 52.1734948526036, 52.1950929360671, 
        52.1933575142806, 52.2008541941149, 52.1996442253934, 
        52.1993793408531, 52.1997865033006, 52.1995285782159, 
        52.2020381720135), .Dim = c(10L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
            NULL, c("coords.x1", "coords.x2"))), bbox = structure(c(-119.588190960814, 
        52.1708538774377, -119.509868345652, 52.2020381720135
        ), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(c("coords.x1", 
        "coords.x2"), c("min", "max"))), proj4string = new("CRS", 
            projargs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")), 
    new("SpatialPointsDataFrame", data = structure(list(idcollar = c(84301L, 
    84301L, 84301L, 84301L, 84301L, 84301L, 84301L, 84301L, 84301L, 
    84301L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 10L)), 
        coords.nrs = numeric(0), coords = structure(c(-119.016244690108, 
        -119.015521244171, -119.001243189449, -118.984576146833, 
        -118.979134447251, -118.993547652551, -119.002675814604, 
        -119.013983482441, -119.016526478337, -119.036672059712, 
        51.9893159182159, 51.9890901415176, 51.983650964071, 
        51.9894795913573, 52.0011534623706, 51.9841837859342, 
        51.984066244934, 51.9881747449946, 51.9862240973867, 
        51.986048859706), .Dim = c(10L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
            NULL, c("coords.x1", "coords.x2"))), bbox = structure(c(-119.036672059712, 
        51.983650964071, -118.979134447251, 52.0011534623706), .Dim = c(2L, 
        2L), .Dimnames = list(c("coords.x1", "coords.x2"), c("min", 
        "max"))), proj4string = new("CRS", projargs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")))
```

I can calculate the home range for a defined percentage for each data set:

```
TEST_HR <- map(.x=TEST_POINTS, ~adehabitatHR::mcp(xy=.x, percent=95))
```

but I am struggling to calculate home ranges of varying percentages for the same list of inputs.  My assumption was to use map2:

```
TEST_HR_MULTI <- map2(.x=TEST_POINTS, .y=PERCENTS, ~~adehabitatHR::mcp(xy=.x, percent=.y))
```

but this fails because .x and .y are not the same length. I can't really transform the input data to have percent as a new column because the mcp function requires a SP data set of only locations and animal id. Is there a purrr method to do something like this , or will I need to figure out how to write it as a series of for loops?

Comment: is `adehabitatHR::mcp` vectorized on the `percent` argument? ie can you do `adehabitatHR::mcp(xy=.x, percent=c(80,90,95))`? if so then do `map(.x=TEST_POINTS, ~adehabitatHR::mcp(xy=.x, percent=PERCENTS))` otherwise do `map(.x=TEST_POINTS, ~Vectorize(adehabitatHR::mcp, 'percent')(xy=.x, percent=PERCENTS))`

Comment: Could use `tidyr`,`dplyr` -> `tibble(TEST_POINTS = TEST_POINTS) %>% mutate(tmp = list(PERCENTS)) %>% unnest(PERCENTS) %>% mutate(ouput = map2(.x=TEST_POINTS, .y=PERCENTS, ~~adehabitatHR::mcp(xy=.x, percent=.y)))` .

Comment: Thanks, both of those get the job done.